# Scroll background container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I am trying to build scrollable screen, where brown background Container must scroll with List of elements when black container near this container.
How can I do it?
I thought about Positioned, but I can't build items above SliverAppbar even if I build it in different Stack.

May I build body above SliverAppbar or how can I realise this?

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColors.mainBrown,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(30)),
        ),
      ),
      CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          const SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 70,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
            titleSpacing: 22,
            title: Text('AppBar'),
          ),
          SliverPadding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
            sliver: SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                Card(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.brown,
                    height: 200,
                  ),
                ),
                Card(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    height: 250,
                  ),
                ),
                Card(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    height: 300,
                  ),
                ),
                Card(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                ),
                Card(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                ),
                Card(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    height: 150,
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: it would be great if you share the UI design you want to implement.

Comment: @CarlosSandoval like this https://disk.yandex.ru/i/UxOnG2EvN1gWNA

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like solution in my case, but I am not sure, this is right way

```
  late ScrollController _frontController, _backController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _frontController = ScrollController();
    _backController = ScrollController();
    _frontController.addListener(test);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _frontController.dispose();
    _backController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  test() {
    if (_frontController.position.pixels >= 215) {
      _backController.jumpTo(_frontController.offset - 215);
    }
  }

 return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _backController,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: AppColors.mainBrown,
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(30)),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 1000,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          CustomScrollView(
            controller: _frontController,
            slivers: [
              const SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 70,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                elevation: 0,
                shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                titleSpacing: 22,
                title: Text('AppBar'),
              ),
              SliverPadding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                sliver: SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                    Card(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.brown,
                        height: 200,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Card(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        height: 250,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Card(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        height: 300,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Card(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Card(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        height: 100,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Card(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        height: 150,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).